# Using code with copyright waiver and no license

Tags: public-domain, unlicensed-code

I have come across [a file](https://github.com/DidierStevens/DidierStevensSuite/blob/master/zipdump.py) in a repository that says the following

> source code put in public domain by xxx, no copyright

It does not contain an explicit license, just the aforementioned waiver.

My question is, is that enough for me to use the code however I want?

Comment: This question has an answer.  You certainly don't have to love it, and offering a bounty is an excellent way to solicit others, but it would be very helpful to understand what you don't like about it.  Are there things it doesn't cover that you want to know?  Do you find any of the argument unconvincing, and if so, which bit(s)?  Do you simply not like the conclusion it reaches and want someone to give a different answer (eg, sure, you can use any of that code)?  You say you want more attention on this question; it would be helpful to know what kind.

Comment: Also, a link to the repo in question might well offer fruitful ground for answers based on further investigation.

Comment: Different opinion if any. Is that not allowed in here?

Comment: Does that answer all of your questions @MadHatter?

Comment: It's definitely a help, for which thanks, though a link would've been even more of one.  I hope you get an answer that better pleases you, though I fear the current one's basically nailed it.

Comment: Repository is wrong per se. It was in a specific file in a private repository, I don't know if I can share that. I think the original file was distributed as an archive on a blog. The question is more about my curiosity than to find an ultimate truth. The current answer is informative and I'd accept that after I feel enough time has passed.

Comment: https://github.com/DidierStevens/DidierStevensSuite/blob/master/zipdump.py this is the original file

Comment: Could you elaborate on "however I want"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: "however I want" is a hypothetical question. If I knew how I would use such a file in the future I would have stated that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This type of notice is known as public domain dedication. Only the copyright holder can do so.

> Only the copyright owner can dedicate a work to the public domain. -
> https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/public-domain/welcome/

It is used to release a work into the public domain so that anyone can use it freely.

> If, upon viewing a work, you see words such as, “This work is
> dedicated to the public domain,” then it is free for you to use. -
> https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/public-domain/welcome/

However a dedication must be done properly to be effective under law. It's unclear if this dedication is.

> Dedicating works to the public domain is difficult if not impossible
> [...] Few if any jurisdictions have a process for doing so easily and
> reliably. -
> https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/

Additionally not all jurisdictions allow making a dedication to the public domain. So the author may not have the authority to make this dedication.

> many legal systems effectively prohibit any attempt by these owners to
> surrender rights automatically -
> https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/

Keep in mind this dedication, if valid, only applies in the jurisdictions the Copyright holder had Copyright in, and possibly in some jurisdictions with the necessary foreign Copyright recognition, and necessary permittance of dedication to Public Domain. So, it's possible this work is not protected by Copyright in your jurisdiction. It's also possible that it is protected, and can't be dedicated to Public Domain in your jurisdiction. It's possible that it is protected, can be dedicated to Public Domain, but that this dedication doesn't meet the requirements of your jurisdiction, even if does meet requirements of the Copyright holder's jurisdiction. So there's a lot variables here making it hard to determine if this dedication is valid.

> There is no such thing as an "international copyright" -
> https://www.stopfakes.gov/article?id=What-is-a-Copyright

> most countries offer protection to foreign works under certain
> conditions -
> https://www.stopfakes.gov/article?id=Is-My-Copyright-Good-in-Other-Countries

It would be safest to contact the Copyright holder, and request they grant you permission to use the work under your desired opensource license, in case their dedication is not legally recognized.

---

*Note: I am not a lawyer. This answer is for education purposes only, and is not intended to constitute legal advice.*

*Copyright James Daniel Marrs Ritchey. This material was created for
submission at
'https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10116/using-code-with-copyright-waiver-and-no-license',
but can also be alternatively obtained from
'https://snippetly.blogspot.com/2020/07/public-domain-dedication.html' under the terms of any of the
following licenses: Ritchey Permissive License v10
(https://jamesdanielmarrsritchey.blogspot.com/2020/07/ritchey-permissive-license-v10.html),
The MIT License (https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).*